# HTTP client example on win32

Tags: c++, windows, http, asynchronous, windows-xp

I wanted to develop one HTTP example on win32 platform, which is asynchronous.

I am new to win32 programming, what are the api and library win32 platform  provides for HTTP send and receive request? I am using Windows XP with VS 2005.

If any example is available please provide a link to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use WinHTTP library. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383138%28VS.85%29.aspx) is an sample on Asynchronous completion.

Answer (score 12):

[Window HTTP Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273(VS.85).aspx) "provides developers with an HTTP client application programming interface (API) to send requests through the HTTP protocol to other HTTP servers."

[HTTP Server API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364510(VS.85).aspx) "enables applications to communicate over HTTP without using Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS)"

Comment: thanks for the link and information, it wil be of more use to me i guess

Answer (score 4):

Generally I'd recommend something cross-platform like cURL, POCO, Qt, or Asio (pretty modern and nice). However, here is a Windows example using `IXMLHTTPRequest`:

```
// TODO: error handling

#include <atlbase.h>
#include <msxml6.h>

HRESULT hr;
CComPtr<IXMLHTTPRequest> request;

hr = request.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_XMLHTTP60);
hr = request->open(
    _bstr_t("GET"),
    _bstr_t("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"),
    _variant_t(VARIANT_FALSE),
    _variant_t(),
    _variant_t());
hr = request->send(_variant_t());

// get status - 200 if succuss
long status;
hr = request->get_status(&status);

// load image data (if url points to an image)
VARIANT responseVariant;
hr = request->get_responseStream(&responseVariant);
IStream* stream = (IStream*)responseVariant.punkVal;
CImage image = new CImage();
image->Load(stream);
stream->Release();
```

Comment: Do you know which piece of software supplies IXMLHTTPRequest as a COM class? Internet Explorer?

Comment: I believe it's part of the MSXML SDK, which looks to be a library for Windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753804(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

[Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is a nice synchronous/asynchronous library which has everything you need for HTTP servers/clients. It has some extensive examples on HTTP servers, and the relevant clients. Now if you are new to C++ in general this library may be a little cryptic. You could always go have a look at MSDN if you want a more from scratch approach.

Comment: boost.asio provides a mechanism for you to formulate your own http requests by hand; the windows http services encapsulate the protocol for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example

https://github.com/pedro-vicente/lib_netsockets

A C++ light wrapper for POSIX and Winsock sockets

It uses HTTP GET to retrieve a file from a web server, both server and file are command line parameters. The remote file is saved to a local copy.