# Send HTTP GET or POST request using C in WIndows

Tags: c, http, http-post, http-get

I want to send HTTP GET or POST request using C in Windows. I m using Dev C++ to compile the code. I don't know what library or what to use to get it working.

My HTTP GET request will be like this: http://example.com/search.php?s=coffee

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP client example on win32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107862/http-client-example-on-win32)

Comment: So many duplicates, so easy to find them.

Answer (score 0):

[**Windows sock API**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock) 2 is compatible (or almost) with [**Berkeley sockets**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets). Functions like `socket()`, `write()`, `send()` are available. It's no hard to do. But you still can use a library such as [**curl**](http://curl.haxx.se/)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a newbie answer. Windows automatically comes with curl. So in theory you could just use the system() function in C execute a curl command.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    system("curl http://example.com/search.php?s=coffee");
}
```