# How to make Paypal REST API request using Winsock C++

Tags: c++, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox, winsock

I want to integrate Paypal into my C++ project using Winsock and sending raw string requests to Paypal REST API. I think my code is almost working, however I am getting error 403 which means some parameters are probably wrong. Here is the code with my attempt to request the token (I am following Paypal guide https://developer.paypal.com/reference/get-an-access-token/):

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

void Call_REST(
    std::string verb,
    std::string resource,
    std::vector<std::string> headers,
    std::string body,
    std::string& response)
{
    std::string req = "";
    WSADATA wsaData;
    struct hostent* host;
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;

    // Init WSA
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
        Logger::ThrowBox("WSAStartup failed.");

    // Make socket
    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    // Find host header
    for (auto& h : headers)
        if (h.find("Host: ") != std::string::npos)
        {
            // Extract host name and port from Host header
            std::string hostname = h.substr(6, h.find_last_of(":") - 6);
            u_short port = std::stoi(h.substr(h.find_last_of(":") + 1));

            host = gethostbyname(hostname.c_str());
            SockAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
            SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

            // Connect socket
            if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0)
            {
                int error = WSAGetLastError();
                Logger::ThrowBox("Could not connect.\nError: " + std::to_string(error));
            }
            else
                OutputDebugStringA("Connected!");
        }

    // Append HTTP verb and resource
    req += verb + " " + resource + " HTTP/1.1\r\n";

    // Append all the headers
    for (auto& h : headers) req += h + "\r\n";
    req += "Content-length: " + std::to_string(body.length()) + "\r\n\r\n";

    // Append body
    req += body;

    // Send request, Receive response, close connection, shut down WSA
    send(Socket, req.c_str(), req.size(), 0);
    char buffer[1024 * 10];
    int nlen;
    while ((nlen = recv(Socket, buffer, 1024 * 10, 0)) > 0)
    {
        response.append(buffer, 0, nlen);
    }
    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();
}

int main()
{
    std::string id; // my id here
    std::string secret; // my secret here
    std::string json = "{\n\"Username\": \"" + id + "\",\n\"Password\": \""
        + secret + "\"\n\"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\"\n}";

    std::string result;
    Call_REST("POST",
        "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
        {
            "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com:80",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Accept-Language: en_US"
        },
        json,
        result);
}
```

Comment: You seem to be sending HTTP when HTTPS is expected. Consider use of the windows HTTP API or newer WinRT HTTP APIs. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/about-wininet  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107862/http-client-example-on-win32

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely check it out. (also HTTPS gave me error code 400 instead of 403)